# Setting Default Values For NSString Properties

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, init

I am trying to determine the recommended way to set default values for NSString properties.

I understand it is not safe to use accessor methods in a class's init and dealloc methods. I often have string constants that I would like to assign default values. What is the recommend way to do this (considering the iVar will be released in the dealloc method)?

For example I understand the following is unsafe:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *identifier;
....

- (id) init
{ 
    self = [super initWithLayer:displayLayer];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.identifier = @"fireSpell01";
    }

    return self;
}
```

Is it ok, or recommend to do this:

```
identifier = [@"fireSpell01" retain];
```

Or must I do this:

```
identifier = [[NSString stringWithString:@"fireSpell01"] retain];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
identifier = @"fireSpell01";
```

There's no need to `retain` the string.  String constants exist for the lifetime of the program and never need to be retained or released.  Doing `[[NSString stringWithString:@"fireSpell01"] retain]` just creates an unnecessary copy and is pointless.

What you want to avoid is using the property setters in the `init` and `dealloc` methods.  Because setters could potentially have side effects that depend on certain state values, you don't want to call them on partially constructed/partially destroyed objects.  It is much better just to assign directly to the ivars and skip the setters during `init`.

Comment: Is it ok if a release is called on identifier (during the dealloc) when it was assigned directly as you suggest?

Comment: @Jay Yes. It is safe to call `retain` and `release` on string constants. It would not make sense otherwise -- a method receiving an `NSString*` does not know how it was allocated and must be able to treat it the same either way.